# I have SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: This type of IN/NOT IN query is not supported yet in Redshift. Is there a way to re write this in NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

And below is the query

```
 WHERE ns.campaign_name IN ('LNG_CS_NA_AC',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_BIS',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_CANADA',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_EROD',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_InterAction',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_Interaction_UK',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_NFL',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_PDS',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_TECH',
                            'LNG_CS_NA_UK',
                            'LNG_CS_UK',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_Asia',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AU_NZ_CS',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AU_NZ_ES',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AU_NZ_Helpline',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AU_NZ_SALES_ENABLEMENT',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AU_NZ_Tech_Sup',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_AUNZ',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_India_Gurugram',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_Japan_Tokyo',
                            'LNG_CSAPAC_Korea_Seoul',
                            'LNG_CSUK',
                            'LNG_CSUK_MLEX',
                            'LNG_GOTC_UK',
                            'LNG_CS_EMEA_CS') -- 'LNG_APAC_Finance'
   AND ns.skill_name NOT LIKE 'cert%'
   AND ns.skill_name NOT IN
       ('APAC_FINANCE_MY', 'APAC_FINANCE_INDIA', 'APAC_FINANCE_SG')
   AND ns.contact_start_dts > '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Error message:

> This type of IN/NOT IN query is not supported yet in Redshift.

Is there a way to re write this in NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Please show us your full query, thanks

Comment: Cant show it. query too long

Comment: Which line is causing that error message? (Such that, if you remove the line, the error disappears.)

Comment: Your ´NOT IN´ list only has three names.  Have you tried rewriting as `AND ns.skill_name <> 'APAC_FINANCE_MY' AND ns.skill_name <> 'APAC_FINANCE_INDIA' AND ns.skill_name <> 'APAC_FINANCE_SG'`?